# How can i call a php method from an array key?

Tags: php

this is my first time asking a question here, so don't judge too harshly.

The logic behind this code is to add specific type of product to database. There are only three specific product classes with getters and setters for distinct product properties and `insert()` method, a class with display and delete pruduct methods, and an abstract class with geters and setters for general product properties, that are included at `config.php`.
The problem (only for one of the types of products all properties are added to the database, for others only the main ones - `sku`, `name` and `price`) lies precisely in this code, since display and deletion work.

Note: I cannot refuse setters and getters, just as I cannot use conditional statements to handle the product type.

Second and maybe classic question: what's wrong with this code and how to fix it?

```
<?php

session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once 'config.php'; // here are the classes

function getClassname() {
    $prod = $_POST['type'];
    return new $prod();
}
 
$methods = [
    'setSize' => $_POST['size'],
    'setWeight' => $_POST['weight'],
    'setHeight' => $_POST['height'],
    'setWidth' => $_POST['width'],
    'setLength' => $_POST['length']
];

function insertData(array $func) 
{
    $product = getClassname();
    $product->dbConnect();
    $product->uniqueSku();
    $product->setSku($_POST['sku']);
    $product->setName($_POST['name']);
    $product->setPrice($_POST['price']);
    foreach ($func as $m => $arg) { 
        if(method_exists($product, $m)){
            $reflect = new ReflectionMethod($_POST['type'], $m);
            $reflect->invoke($product, $arg);
            //$product->$m($arg); doesn't help
        } else {
            break;
        }
    } 
    $product->insert();
}

insertData($methods); 
//header('Location: ...');
```

p.s. I know that some code snippets look weird

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check, if classes and methods exist. Never trust user data since you 're taking an unfiltered post parameter. Anyway ...

### Simple check with method exists.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Marcel\Test;

use InvalidArgumentException;

class Test 
{
    public function foo(string $parameter): void
    {
        echo $parameter;
    }

    public function bar(string $parameter): void
    {
        echo $parameter;
    }
}

$classMethods = [
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'yadda',
];

$instance = new Test();

try {
    foreach ($classMethods as $method) {
        if (!method_exists($instance, $method)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                'Method "%s" does not exist in "%s".',
                $method,
                get_class($instance),
            ));
        }

        $instance->{$method}(sprintf('"%s" really exists!', $method));
    }
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

// output:
// "foo" really exists!
// "bar" really exists!
// "yadda" does not exist in "Marcel\Test\Test"
```

Watch the curly brackets around the method name, when calling it.

### Check and call with reflection

The same works with reflection. A small advice from my side. Always watch out for exceptions. The `ReflectionMethod` class throws a `ReflectionException` when the method does not exist on the given class instance.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Marcel\Test;

use ReflectionException;
use ReflectionMethod;

class Test 
{
    public function foo(string $parameter): void
    {
        echo $parameter;
    }

    public function bar(string $parameter): void
    {
        echo $parameter;
    }
}

$classMethods = [
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'yadda',
];

$instance = new Test();

try {
    foreach ($classMethods as $method) {
        $reflection = new ReflectionMethod($instance, $method);
        $reflection->invoke($instance, sprintf('"%s" really exists!', $method));
    }
} catch (ReflectionException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

// output:
// "foo" really exists!
// "bar" really exists!
// Method Marcel\Test\Test::yadda() does not exist
```

Comment: Hello, Marcel. Can we contact somewhere out of Stack to talk about it?